# Is there any way to find a specific data frame in R files?

Tags: r, dataframe

i'm new to R and I have a problem with finding a specific data frame and it's code in R files,Is there any way to find it at all?

beforehand I'm sorry if this question comes across alittle basic or strange.

Any little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know which specific `RData` file contains the data frame or could it be located in any number of files?

Comment: I want to find the r file in which for the first time I have defined and write the code for that specific data frame.I don't know in which r file I have defined this data frame for the first time.Is there any way to find the definition of it?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this other than checking each RData file individually.

Comment: Do you at least know the file type? Can it be `CSV`, `TXT` or is it surely `RData`? The best way to solve your problem is with OS commands, not `R`.

Comment: I know it's R data.I am wondering if there is a way to fix the problem for future but now I find my data frame by chance.Thank you.I'll be so glad if I can find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `iris` data.
First load the data:

```
data(iris)
```

Then print and use it:

```
print(iris)
```

Comment: I want to find the first place i defined the mentioned specific data frame and I don't know in which r file it was.how should i fix this problem?